# django-braces AccessMixin dispatch method

Tags: python, mixins, superclass

On the `django-braces` github repo there's a method call that some of the `AccessMixin` subclasses do to their super class, [here](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_access.py#L63)

They call `super(Klass, self).dispatch(...)`, but that method is not defined on that super class, what is actually going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Mixin - they're not meant to be subclassed on their own, but used in conjunction with one of Django's [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), which *will* provide the `dispatch` method - like so:

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    pass
```